Specify target sheet from google form results
I have a google sheet for entering daily weight on a number of clients that is linked to a form which populates a sheet in the spreadsheet. The title of the sheet is assigned by the form. If I edit the form to add a new client, the form response sheet name changes and my code doesn't work. I can hard code the name each time, but that involves several lines of code. Is there a way to assign a variable based on the sheet name which is always the first sheet in the book?
I have tried creating the variable and replacing the sheet name (in bold) but get an error message: 4:21:26 PM  Error
Exception: Invalid argument
SheetName1  @ Weights1.gs:11
function SheetName1() {
  //Get name of goat from form results
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName()); 
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 5").getRange(2,2).getValue()
  Logger.log(sh1)
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sh1), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Form Responses 5\'!C2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(**sheet**), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sh1), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Form Responses 5\'!A2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 5'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
}

